# Bash local variable initialization

Tags: bash, shell, variable, function

How does Bash initialize local variables? Will the following commands **always** do the same thing (when used inside a function)?

```
local foo
local foo=
local foo=""
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`local foo=""` and `local foo=` are exactly equivalent. In both cases, the right-hand side of the equal sign is an empty string.

`local foo` and `local foo=` are different: `local foo` leaves `foo` unset while `local foo=` sets `foo` to an empty string. More precisely, `local foo` creates a local variable, and that variable is initially unset. A subsequent assignment `foo=…` sets the local value, and that assignment can be combined with the `local` statement. Witness:

```
bash-4.3$ demo () {
  local unset empty=
  echo "unset=\"${unset-(not set)}\" empty=\"${empty-(not set)}\""
}
bash-4.3$ demo
unset="(not set)" empty=""
```

This is the same behavior as ksh (except that in ksh you need to use the keyword `typeset` instead of `local`). On the other hand, in zsh, `local foo` sets `foo` to an empty string.

Comment: Not quite correct: The first form does not **unset** the variable. For example, if you have first a statement `local x=5` in your function, and then a `local x` in the same function, x would still be 5.

Comment: I've noticed that any of these 3 ways to initialize make the -z, -n and -f completely equivalent in a test. foo always passes the tests unless initialized to something other than "".